# How do I reproduce the Facebook timeline image onmouseover zoom effect without expanding the image?

Tags: css, image

Since a few months or so, Facebook has a nice tiny subtle extra design feature. When you are browsing the timeline and hover over a picture (that meets the requirements) it zooms a little bit (perhaps 2% or so) but it does not change the dimensions of the image. It is as if the image is behind a transparent window.

Now this might be a stupid question but I can't seem to think of a way to  reproduce this behavior. Do you guys know?

Answer (score 1):

No sure what you mean as I couldn't find the effect on my Facebook. But judging from your description I have made an example of what I think you want for you.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LkbwLk20/1/)

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://cdn.fstoppers.com/styles/full/s3/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/fstoppers_umf_barrie3_featured.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Fried Chicken. This is correct.  I had initially expected scale to also change the dimensions. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. If it worked for you please can you accept my answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can click mark answer as accepted. Here is a link to a guide on how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Thanks.